# extjs 6 modern combobox with infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, infinite-scroll, extjs6-modern

Based on [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?351786-Combo-box-with-28000-records&p=1193781&viewfull=1#post1193781) comment from **mitchellsimoens** at sencha forums i tried to implement an infinite scrolling combobox in **extjs 6.5.2 modern**.

The thing is that setting the `combobox` store to a `virtual store` produces this error: `Uncaught TypeError: a.setExtraKeys is not a function`.

I also set the `floatedPicker` to:

```
{
xtype: 'boundlist',
infinite: true,
// BoundListNavigationModel binds to input field
// Must only be enabled when list is visible
navigationModel: {
    disabled: true
},
scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
loadingHeight: 70,
maxHeight: 300,
floated: true,
axisLock: true,
hideAnimation: null
}
```

Is there a way to implement an infinite scrolling combobox in extjs 6 modern without changing the default picker to a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this actually works:

```
floatedPicker: {
            xtype: 'boundlist',
            infinite: true,
            // BoundListNavigationModel binds to input field
            // Must only be enabled when list is visible
            navigationModel: {
                disabled: true
            },
            plugins: {
                listpaging: {
                    autoPaging: true,
                    loadMoreText: 'More records..',
                    noMoreRecordsText: 'No more records.'
                }
            },
            scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
            loadingHeight: 70,
            maxHeight: 300,
            floated: true,
            axisLock: true,
            hideAnimation: null,
            variableHeights: true
        }
```

It's a bit ugly when loading but it works.

Also i used an `Ext.data.store`. Virtual store don't work with comboboxes.